# Show custom message on chrome infobar using selenium chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I want to show custom message on the chrome infobar instead of "Chrome is being controlled by an automated test software".
How is this possible using selenium?

Comment: No, this text is [not customizable](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/app/generated_resources.grd?l=9051-9053&rcl=ac7eccb3) and you [can't suppress it either](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/startup/startup_browser_creator_impl.cc?l=791-792&rcl=ac7eccb3) (due to `--enable-automation` command line switch used by Selenium).

Comment: this sure can be suppressed using (--disable-infobars). And there should be an option to change it because inforbar are available in chrome developer options. a lot of apps make sure of it.

Comment: Well, you can suppress all infobars, but not this one individually.

Comment: My intention is not to suppress. I just want to show my own custom infobar. Editing this or creating the new one is not my concern,

Comment: You can add this feature yourself and build your own fork of Chromium.

Comment: @ashkaps Were you able to find a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any way of having custom infobars in Chrome.
However, there is usually more than one way to skin a cat. If you need a mechanism to give test meta-info to the tester (iteration #, variable values, test title, etc) that works for all browsers, then you can just change the title of the page, like this:

```
String javascript = "document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent = 'yourtext';";
((JavascriptExecutor) Common.driver).executeScript(javascript);
```

Note that while you're still in Java, you can modify "yourtext" any way you want.
Just make sure that you're not checking the title of the web page as part of your selenium test.